# Derivatives Of The Cumulative Normal Distribution Function

Tags: calculus, statistics

I have a optimization problem where I want to calculate the derivative of a cumulative multivariate normal function with respect to x. Still, x appears both in the upper limit and in the variance.  Take Φ for the cumulative normal distribution function.
$$\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi(\pmb{g}x;\pmb{0};\pmb{f}x\pmb{f}')$$

Any insights or references are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\Phi(\mathbf{g}x;\mathbf{0};\mathbf{f}x\mathbf{f}')=\int_{\{\mathbf{z}\ge\mathbf{g}x\}}\frac{1}{(2\pi x)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{ff}'}}}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}\mathbf{z}\cdot (\mathbf{ff}')^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{z}'\right)d\mathbf{z}
\end{align}
$$
Make a change of variable $\mathbf{y}=\frac{1}{x}\mathbf{z}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\Phi(\mathbf{g}x;\mathbf{0};\mathbf{f}x\mathbf{f}') = \int_{\{\mathbf{y}\ge\mathbf{g}\}}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{ff}'}}}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\mathbf{y}\cdot (\mathbf{ff}')^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{y}'\right)d\mathbf{y} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

We observer that $x$ appears only in the interand of $(1)$, so the derivative can be easily deduced
$$\frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x} = \int_{\{\mathbf{y}\ge\mathbf{g}\}}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\det{\mathbf{ff}'}}}\cdot \left(-\frac{\mathbf{y}\cdot (\mathbf{ff}')^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{y}'}{2}  \right)  \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2x}\mathbf{y}\cdot (\mathbf{ff}')^{-1}\cdot\mathbf{y}'\right)d\mathbf{y} \tag{2}
$$
Don't know much about $\mathbf{f}$, but if $\mathbf{f}$ is an inversible matrix, we can make a change of variable $\mathbf{t}=\mathbf{yf}'^{-1}$ and $(2)$ can be computed analytically.

Comment: Why is x not in the variance, but is the variance written down as ff'?

Comment: @KurtZ. because of the first change of variable in (1)